# captcha response and request is always null

Tags: apex

I am trying to implement captcha in community user registration page but challenge and response i.e `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recaptcha_challenge_field')` and `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recaptcha_response_field')` is always null in controller. The same code I have implmented in other page and there captcha is working fine. But in user registration page captcha is always invalid because challenge and response is null.

Please help me fix this issue !!
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have parameters in user registration page?

Comment: Ya I have referred this site https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Adding_CAPTCHA_to_Force.com_Sites and following the same.